# Can one break fast if he is overworked?

Tags: sawm, ramadan

I'm a guy of age 23. I work in an office where people don't care in what state are you and makes me work real bad. It's the month of Ramadan and I have a really difficult time in keeping my fast. I become so claustophobic that I feel just to lie down. Also, it's really hot and early in the morning at 9:00 a.m. I feel thirsty, and by 2-3 it's feel that I need water badly. Once, I went to gargle, but it soothed me so much that I ended up drinking water, thus I broke my fast. I'm really sorry for this!
Is it fine if I just don't keep the fasts at all?

Comment: Allah likes three things: 1) Fast of hot climate, 2) Wudhu in cold climate 3) And Ibadat in teenage. Just for information :)

Answer (score 1):

Fasting the month of Ramadan is obligatory.

> كتب عليكم الصيام
>
> Decreed upon you is fasting
>
> <sup>— [Quran 2:183](https://quran.com/2/183)</sup>

> شهر رمضان ... فمن شهد منكم الشهر فليصمه
>
> The month of Ramadhan ... So whoever sights the month, let him fast it
>
> <sup>— [Quran 2:185](https://quran.com/2/185)</sup>

As such, it is unlikely that you will find someone willing to admit petty excuses. Especially considering that there are people in worse conditions than yours who are also fasting: including people of old age and those who have to do manual labor and do not have the luxury of working from an office.

If you have difficulty, then you should find ways to make it easier rather than leaving an obligatory duty. Eat and drink wisely in *sahr* and *iftar*, remain indoors and in air-conditioning as much as possible, pace out your daily activities etc. Once you accept that you *have* to fast, you will find a way.